# BASH - find line (match string) begins with Text and Forward slash

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, matching, slash

I am trying to find (match string) line in file, that starts (begin) with **TEST /**

this works, TEST with whitespace:

```
if [[ "$LINE" == 'TEST '* ]]
then    
   echo $LINE
fi
```

texh with forward slash, doesnt work - how can I make this works?

```
if [[ "$LINE" == 'TEST /'* ]]
then
   echo $LINE
fi
```

any advice?

I have red other topics, questions, but no luck..........

Comment: What are you testing for LINE? I tested `LINE="TEST /foo"` and your code worked as expected

Comment: LINE is one line from text file, that contais many, many different lines (alphanumeric mix - numbers, letters, special characters.....). Whether LINE starts or begin with ...TEST /... in Bash

Comment: Can you show an example of a line that you are expecting to match but isn't?

Comment: example1: TEST / testing1 b2555 ££
example2: TEST / testing2 ££ $
example3: TEST / 2555 ££ + 32

Comment: That also works with your example

Comment: `LINE='TEST / testing1 b2555 ££ example1: TEST / testing2 ££ $'; [[ "$LINE" == 'TEST /'* ]] && echo yes` -> prints "yes"

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine no problem on my side.
But if you want to select lines that start with some patterns i suggest you the =~ binary operator. More info at https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html
e.g

```
LINE='TEST / nhdjsnhdfsdndsndasdfn'
pattern='^TEST /'
if [[ "$LINE" =~ $pattern ]]
then
   echo $LINE
fi
```

Comment: `==` should work just fine for what the OP is trying to do. Whatever problem they're having with `==` is probably going to affect `=~`, too.